# ASP.NET/C# connect to Oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, iis, visual-studio-2012

I need to access a view on an oracle server with an ASP.NET website.  It works if I debug the website through visual studio(press F5 in VS2012), but when I go to the version hosted on my local IIS (LocalHost/) I get this error:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

A lot of the information I'm finding is related to the deprecated `System.Data.OracleClient` and I'm using `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` File version 4.112.3.0, Assembly version 2.112.3.0.

I set the AppPool it's running in to `Enable 32-Bit Application=True` based on some other people with a similar issue, I think everything else is default settings.

I've tried using the gacutil to make sure it is installed in the gac.

I also made a small winForms application that works and can access the data.

I've tried a couple connection strings:

This one works:

```
"Data Source=SOURCE;Persist Security Info=True;Password=****;User Id=****;"
```

This one doesn't work, I can't figure out a valid `SERVICE_NAME`:

```
"user id=****;password=****;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=****)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****)));"
```

I always get this error:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Places I've looked for `SERVICE_NAME`

I checked the connection I was able to establish with the first connection string and the `SERVICE_NAME` was either blank or `sys$users` depending on the query I ran.

I found three files named `tnsnames.ora`; one was completely blank, the `SERVICE_NAME` in the other two were `Worker` and `<database service name>`.

NOTE: I don't have access to the server, just credentials for this one view.

Comment: are you aware that you do not need to create your datasource that way.. we currently use Oracle 11.x and we installed the oracle client 32 and 64 bit version and when connecting we use the same construct like how we connect to Sql Server if you must do it using `TNS Names` make sure that the TNS Names file is located on the machine look at this link as well [C# Connection Strings Oracle DB](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

Comment: I tried a string similar to that (see the first one). it works in the desktop application and if I run the website in debug mode through visual studio. if I go to the website at localhost in a browser I get the first error.  I only tried the second connection string after searching for a solution to the initial error.

Comment: you need to have that Oracle Client installed on the remote location find yourself a DBA or someone whom has admin experience when it comes to setting up and or Installing Oracle Client on Remote host..

Comment: Eww. Don't use any Oracle library that requires you to install the Oracle Client. That's just a headache. Instead, use the [Oracle Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/). It has no external dependencies. Then go to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) and use the "Omitting TNSNAMES.ORA" style connection string.

Comment: @mason: How do I find the SERVICE_NAME? that connection string looks a lot like the second one I tried in my question.

Comment: @MethodMan: Thanks, I'll look into installing the oracle client and if that is a workable solution on Monday.

Comment: I had the same issue in our current environment ..that's how we discovered that the .NET dll for Oracle 64bit had issues.. but we were able to change our build to use 32bit vs AnyCpu..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `SERVICE_NAME` with this: `select sys_context('userenv','db_name') from dual;` and used the second connection string from the question:

```
"user id=****;password=****;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=****)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****)));"
```

Thanks for all the help.